# postDelayed() not woking properly

Tags: android, postdelayed

i want a number of images to be set as background one after another every few seconds.
i asked how to do this and i got to know i should use handler().postDelayed() to perform that.
i used to following code to implement what i wanted but it didnot work for me.
i'm getting just one image and it is not changing at all.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        count += (count+1)%drawablearray.length;   
        rl.setBackgroundResource(drawablearray[count]);
           }
  }, 5000);
```

please help me if i'm wrong somewhere or tell me some other way to implement this.
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you perferming this operation once or n number of times.?

Comment: i have 5 images which i want to be repeated again and again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to repost your runnable:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        count += (count+1)%drawablearray.length;   
        rl.setBackgroundResource(drawablearray[count]);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);   
        }
  }, 5000);
```